# background-size: cover и позиции элементов

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, svg

Есть нестандартное изображение заднего фона, которое я растягиваю по всему размеру блока с помощью `background-size: cover;` при масштабировании сталкиваюсь со следующей проблемой, положение текста меняется, а изображение меняется на основе размера блока:
Исходное состояние:
https://clip2net.com/s/43ZuVFE
Что выдает при масштабированиее:
https://clip2net.com/s/43ZuRSS

Как должно быть: https://c2n.me/43ZvaVF

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу?

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Приложите минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wz34v9xj/

Comment: То есть текст должен находиться всегда здесь https://c2n.me/4400X6h но при ресайзе он уплывает https://c2n.me/4400ZBa

Comment: никуда не уплывает. Как был padding-top: 100px; так и остался. Текст фиксированный, фон - "плавающий". Так и должно быть. Вполне очевидное поведение.

Answer (score 2):

### Решение SVG+CSS

Чтобы обеспечить кроссбраузерность и адаптивность при любом размере дисплея можно воспользоваться следующей техникой:

- Добавляете изображение фона с помощью тега SVG `<image>`
- Текст добавляете с помощью тега `<text>` и позиционируете его с помощью координат `x` и `y` 
  Оборачиваете svg код в контейнер. Теперь у вас это будет самостоятельный блок, начальные размеры, которого можно менять с помощью процентов и встроить в любое место вашей веб страницы.

*Надеюсь ответ вам будет полезен.*

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
text {
font-size:48px;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
fill:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1055 717" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
     
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORJ3b.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
<text x="550" y="200"  >TECT </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Другая картинка, кроме ссылки не требуется ничего менять в коде. 
Адаптивность также осталась и текст не меняет своё расположение:

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
text {
font-size:48px;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
fill:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1055 717" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
     
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vamst.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
<text x="550" y="200"  >TECT </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @user352495 Если решение было вам полезно, не забудьте поставить галочку рядом с ответом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `background-size: 100%;` а для более точного ответа, прикрепите ваш код.